# Cannot Find ApplicationDeployment in System.Deployment

Tags: c#, wpf, clickonce

I have a built program and I am trying to change out the default clickOnce update checker with a hard programmed one. I have added the `using System.Deployment;` but it does not contain the assembly information I need to call. What am I missing here? I have searched MSDN but it keeps saying this is the correct namespace to call.

The error shows as:
`The name ApplicationDeployment does not exist in the current context`

Code from Program:

```
        private void UpdateApplication()
    {
        if (ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed)
        {
            ApplicationDeployment ad = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment;
            ad.CheckForUpdateCompleted += new CheckForUpdateCompletedEventHandler(ad_CheckForUpdateCompleted);
            ad.CheckForUpdateProgressChanged += new DeploymentProgressChangedEventHandler(ad_CheckForUpdateProgressChanged);

            ad.CheckForUpdateAsync();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`ApplicationDeployment` class is present in `System.Deployment.Application` namespace and not `System.Deployment`. Change your using accordingly or try with the full name `System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment`

Comment: That is the problem there is only System.Deployment.Internal and says Application does not exist.

Comment: @Saran You need to Add a reference to System.Deployment.dll in your project.

Comment: That's the real answer -- you need to add the reference to your project.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `using System.Deployment.Application;` as well.

Comment: That is the problem there is only System.Deployment.Internal and says Application does not exist.